# Selecting empty rows in table with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery along with the jQuery validation plug-in.

I have a table where each column after the first column contains a form field such as a checkbox, a text field, etc. I use `<th>` for headers, so only `<tr>` elements have form fields.

How do I select all rows whose entire form fields are empty? By empty, I'm talking about a text field with an undefined value, a checkbox unchecked, a select field with nothing selected, etc. I'm not supposed to select a row if it has at least one non-empty form field.

Is this possible? Can someone please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This shouldn't be too difficult using `.filter()`:

```
$('tr').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).find('input:text:not(:empty), textarea:not(:empty), input:checked, option:selected').length;
});
```

This searches the `tr` to find

- non-empty text inputs
- non-empty textareas
- checked checkboxes/radio boxes
- selected option elements

and returns false if any are found (i.e. removes them from the selection).